# Laravel SelectRaw

Tags: laravel

I am working on task where I need get the counts of record and I am using the selectRaw. previously I was fetching the all the counts from the past 30 days but now I want to fetch without date limit except the closed cases. the closed cases should have 30 days limit. here is my current code.

```
$date = Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
        
        $store_ids = ($store_ids != '') ? $store_ids : $user->stores()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        
        $complaint = DB::table('complaint')
                        ->join('complaint_status', 'complaint_status.id', '=', 'complaint.status_id')
                        ->join('complaint_staff', 'complaint_staff.complaint_id', '=', 'complaint.id');

        if ($company_id != '') {
            $complaint = $complaint->where('complaint.company_id', '=', $company_id);
        }
        
       
        
        $complaint = $complaint->where('complaint.created_at', '>=', $date)
                        ->where('complaint_staff.staff_id', '=', $user->id)
                        ->whereIn('complaint.store_id', $store_ids)
                        ->whereNull('complaint_staff.deleted_at')
                        ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '1' then 1 end) as open")
                        ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '2' then 1 end) as in_progress")
                        ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '3' then 1 end) as initial_step")
                        ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '4' then 1 end) as closed")
                        ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.is_escalated = '1' then 1 end) as escalated")
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the grouped orWhere clause:

```
$date = Carbon:: today()->subDays(30);

$store_ids = ($store_ids != '') ? $store_ids : $user->stores()->pluck('id')->toArray();

$complaint = DB:: table('complaint')
    ->join('complaint_status', 'complaint_status.id', '=', 'complaint.status_id')
    ->join('complaint_staff', 'complaint_staff.complaint_id', '=', 'complaint.id');

if ($company_id != '') {
    $complaint = $complaint->where('complaint.company_id', '=', $company_id);
}



$complaint = $complaint->where('complaint_staff.staff_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->whereIn('complaint.store_id', $store_ids)
    ->whereNull('complaint_staff.deleted_at')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($subQuery1) {
            $subQuery1->where('complaint.created_at', '>=', $date)
                ->where("complaint.status_id", "4");
        })
            ->orWhere("complaint.status_id", "!=", "4");

    })
    ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '1' then 1 end) as open")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '2' then 1 end) as in_progress")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '3' then 1 end) as initial_step")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.status_id = '4' then 1 end) as closed")
    ->selectRaw("count(case when complaint.is_escalated = '1' then 1 end) as escalated")
    ->get();
```

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses